# USB - How to Mount when only Physical ID is known

Tags: usb, mount

Running Ubuntu 18.04, new clean install.  The plugged in USB stick is a ZWave receiver (the system is set up for Home Assistant) automation, and also has Docker installed.  The USB does not have a UUID.

''' I would expect sdb (meaning the USB) to show up, which it does not.

```
ha-admin@udll-ha:~$ cat /proc/partitions
major minor  #blocks  name

   7        0      96032 loop0
   7        1      91228 loop1
 179        0   61071360 mmcblk0
 179       16       4096 mmcblk0boot1
 179        8       4096 mmcblk0boot0
   8        0  250059096 sda
   8        1     524288 sda1
   8        2  249532416 sda2
```

''' In the example below, dev 4 is what I want.

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/7p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/9p, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 1, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_acm, 12
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=rtsx_usb, 480M
```

'''  USB:0 is the device I want to automount and be readable

```
*-usb
             description: USB controller
             product: Intel Corporation
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 15
             bus info: pci@0000:00:15.0
             version: 03
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:123 memory:a1200000-a120ffff
           *-usbhost:0
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.15.0-91-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 0
                bus info: usb@1
                logical name: usb1
                version: 4.15
                capabilities: usb-2.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=9 speed=480Mbit/s
              *-usb:0
                   description: Communication device
                   vendor: Sigma Designs, Inc.
                   physical id: 4
                   bus info: usb@1:4
                   version: 0.00
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=cdc_acm maxpower=100mA speed=12Mbit/s
              *-usb:1
                   description: Generic USB device
                   product: USB2.0-CRW
                   vendor: Generic
                   physical id: 5
                   bus info: usb@1:5
                   version: 39.60
                   serial: 20100201396000000
                   capabilities: usb-2.00
                   configuration: driver=rtsx_usb maxpower=500mA speed=480Mbit/s
           *-usbhost:1
                product: xHCI Host Controller
                vendor: Linux 4.15.0-91-generic xhci-hcd
                physical id: 1
                bus info: usb@2
                logical name: usb2
                version: 4.15
                capabilities: usb-3.00
                configuration: driver=hub slots=7 speed=5000Mbit/s
```

How can I get the USB stick to be recognized and mounted?

Comment: Is HA installed in Docker? Or in the base system?

Comment: HA is installed on the base system.  I installed Docker afterwards.  Admittedly, I don't have much experience with Docker.

Comment: Is the device you want under usb:0?  "configuration: driver=cdc_acm"

Comment: Yes for the Sigma Designs, Inc. device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only mass storage devices can be mounted. As can be seen in your device listing, this device is **not** a mass storage device. It cannot be used to create a filesystem and store files on it. Therefore it does not appear in Linux as a block device like `/dev/sdb` and consequentliy isn't listed in `/proc/partitions` either. It is not suitable for mounting.

Your device is detected as a communications device. In order to use it, you need to install appropriate communications software. In your case, this will probably be your Home Automation software, which needs to recognize and support your specific device. If you run the Home Automation software in a docker container you'll probably pass the USB device into that container so that the software will be able so see and access it.